# Howto detect in Docker the container kernel version

Tags: centos, docker

The application stack I want to dockerize shall run within a CentOS container. The installation procedure verifies kernel version to ensure application requirements are met. Currently it is detected using "uname ...".

However the application now detects the host kernel version, which is "UBUNTU ..." and not "CentOS" ..."

Is it possible to detect the container's kernel version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the kernel is the same in the host and in the container. That's the very principle of containerization: the kernel is shared (because actually, a container is a collection of processes running on top of the host kernel, with special isolation properties).

Does that pose a problem for your application?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.Well, in some way it does. 

Setup procedure explicitly checks kernel version. That's the pitfall. Yes, there an option for bypassing, for the moment and as times goes by CentOS will advance it's kernel version I guess ;).

Thank you.